# How to display message box on popup close when changes are not saved in Kendo inline editing grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a popup in which i have created two tabs. Each tab, when opened, contains a kendo inline editable grid. This grid contains three columns among which one contains Edit and Delete button. On edit button click,the selected row will go into edit mode which allows the user to modify the data. This Edit button, once clicked will take its name as Update. After editing, if i do not click on the Update button and simply switch the tab, a message box should be displayed saying that "There are unsaved changes, please save the changes". How do i achieve this? It will be helpful if somebody can please help me resolve this issue.
Code below.

```
 <% Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tab")           
    .Animation(false)       
    .Items(tabstrip =>
     {
         tabstrip.Add().Text("General Points")
           .Selected(true)               
           .Content(() =>
           { %>
                <div id="generalPointGrid"></div> 
                 <% });              
           tabstrip.Add().Text("Important Points")
          .Content(() => { %> <div id="importantPointGrid"></div><% }); 
          })
          .Render(); 
      %>

   <scripts>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: xyzread,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                update: {
                    url: xyzupdate,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                create: {
                    url: xyzcreate,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: function (data) {
                        return xyzdelete,
                    },
                    type: "Delete",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        Remarks: {
                            type: "string"
                        },                           
                        description: {
                            type: "string"
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        });

 var grid = $("#generalPointGrid").kendoGrid({

        dataSource: dataSource,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [ {
            field: "remarks",
            title: "Remarks"              
        }, {
            field: "description",
            title: "Description"               
        }, {
            command: ["edit", "destroy"],
            title: "&nbsp;"              
        }],
        editable: "inline",
        destroy: true
    });


dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: xyzread,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                update: {
                    url: xyzupdate,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                create: {
                    url: xyzcreate,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: function (data) {
                        return xyzdelete,
                    },
                    type: "Delete",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        Remarks: {
                            type: "string"
                        },                           
                        description: {
                            type: "string"
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        });

 var grid = $("#importantPointGrid").kendoGrid({

        dataSource: dataSource,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [ {
            field: "remarks",
            title: "Remarks"              
        }, {
            field: "description",
            title: "Description"               
        }, {
            command: ["edit", "destroy"],
            title: "&nbsp;"              
        }],
        editable: "inline",
        destroy: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI TabStrip has a select event that you can use, to perform your checks before navigating to the new tab. Here is the documentation about it:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events-select